# Cannot invoke 'dispatch_time' with an argument list of tipe (UINT64, UINT64)

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I'm trying to convert a dispatch_time of objective_c for swift but get this error:

```
if !(hasPresented  != nil){
                let vc: TutorialInfoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorialInfoViewController") as! TutorialInfoViewController
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. This is works for me

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 2)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    ptintln("it works!")
})
```